# Using GIMP (v. 2.10.28, Windows 10)) to improve cropped picture

Tags: printing, resolution, images, gimp

I cropped a picture and saved the small part of it that I needed. When I tried to print this picture, its very small. In GIMP, it shows up as 2.7" (W) X 1.8" (H) at a resolution of 96 X 96. I then scaled it up to 6"(W) with corresponding 3.9"(H) using the Scale function in GIMP. I did not change the resolution and then printed it. The print was fuzzy, which I guess is because of the low resolution. Is there anything I can do in GIMP that will keep the size as 6"(W) X 4"(H) and give me a much sharper image. In my mind, I am thinking that what can I do to introduce more pixels while still keeping the size as 6" X 4"?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Maybe try adjusting interpolation? Otherwise, there may be no good way to "add" data to the picture.

Comment: Perhaps you can try using reverse image search to find a bigger version of the original picture?

Comment: Thank you for the three answers.
This is in reply to the first answer - The cropped picture, which is a small part of the larger picture became fuzzy when enlarged. I expected this. I was just asking to see if there is a way to make it sharper using GIMP. 
To the second answer - I have tried the different interpolation methods and they all look fuzzy. It seems 96 pixels per inch is too small.
To the third - This is a personal picture. No other copies.

Comment: pixels per inch or dots per inch are completely meaningless values until you actually print a photo on paper. Until then a picture can't be measured in inches at all. All you have are dimensions in pixels. From your figures, it would appear your picture is 260x170 px. That's just not printable at 6x4" no matter what you try to do to it.

Answer (score 0):

Upscaling images is not as easy as one might believe, there are dedicated software for that; https://topazlabs.com/gigapixel-ai is one, $99 at this writing.

I'm not aware of anything open source or free in the same class.

To learn about the basics of digital image editing techniques;
Have a look on the tutorials at
https://www.cambridgeincolour.com/

These explains what one might need for upscaling among other things (look for "interpolation").

Comment: OnOne Resize is pretty good too [& a slew of new AI-based apps including Photoshop are joining the fray], but scaling up from 'teeny' to 'small' isn't going to be any good at all. OP has it at 96 dpi, which of course makes no sense until you print it, but that would make the original crop only 260x170px [if the vague figures are indeed correct]. There is no software or process yet invented that could print that crisp at 6x4.

Comment: I know almost nothing about photo graphics. Indeed the dimensions in pixels are 254X170. In my mind I thought what needs to be done is to add enough pixels through interpolation so that when printed, it would be a sharper picture. What stops this rom being possible?

Comment: Please check https://www.cambridgeincolour.com/ - it explains it in much better detail than I can do for you, here,